# Why the layout going wrong like one above another? Middle section of React part going behind of Header or in front to the Footer

Tags: reactjs, routes, layout

I can't understand my others page are working good but while i wants to move a particular page it's showing wrong layout.

[image: Coming in front of footer, why?]

**App.js** - if needed
while tapping on a particular movie it'll go to `<Movie/>` page which is `MovieDetails.js` and there is this error occur.

```
  return (
  
    <div className="App">

      
      <Header/>
      <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Layout/>}>
            <Route path="/" element={<Home movies={movies} />} ></Route>
            <Route path="/Trailer/:ytTrailerId" element={<Trailer/>}></Route>
            <Route path="/Reviews/:movieId" element ={<Reviews getMovieData = {getMovieData} movie={movie} reviews ={reviews} setReviews = {setReviews} />}></Route>
            <Route path="*" element = {<NotFound/>}></Route>

            {/* Booking Page  */}
            <Route path='/booking' element={<Booking/>}/>

            {/* Login Page  */}
            <Route path='/login' element={<Login/>}/>

            {/* Payment Page => Proceed to Checkout Button */}
            <Route path='/payment' element= {
              // [ <Header/>,
              <>
                <Elements stripe={promise}>
                  <Payment/>
                </Elements>
              </>
              // ]
            }/>

            {/* Orders Page */}
            <Route path='/orders' element={<Orders/>}/>


            {/* Search Bar Work */}

            {/* Watchlist Page */}
            <Route path='/watchlist' element={<Watchlist/>}/>

            {/* Watched Movie Page */}
            <Route path='/watched' element={<Watched/>}/>


            {/* Popular, Top Rated, Upcoming movie API calling */}

            <Route path='movie/:id' element={ <Movie/> }/>

            <Route path='movies/:type' element={ <MovieList/> }/>

            {/* Popular movies section */}
            <Route path='/popular' element={ <Popular/> }/>

            {/* Popular movies section */}
            <Route path='/toprated' element={ <TopRated/> }/>

            {/* Popular movies section */}
            <Route path='/upcoming' element={ <Upcoming/> }/>


          </Route>
      </Routes>
      <BackToTop/>
      <Footer/>
      <Footbar/>

    </div>
  );
```

**MovieDetails.js**

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from "react"
import "./MovieDetails.css"
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom"

const Movie = () => {
    const [currentMovieDetail, setMovie] = useState()
    const { id } = useParams()

    useEffect(() => {
        getData()
        window.scrollTo(0,0)
    }, [])

    const getData = () => {
        fetch(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/${id}?api_key=${process.env.REACT_APP_TMDB_KEY}&language=en-US&page=1&include_adult=false`)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => setMovie(data))
    }

    return (

        <div className="movie">
            <div className="movie__intro">
                <img className="movie__backdrop" src={`https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original${currentMovieDetail ? currentMovieDetail.backdrop_path : ""}`} />
            </div>
            <div className="movie__detail">
                <div className="movie__detailLeft">
                    <div className="movie__posterBox">
                        <img className="movie__poster" src={`https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original${currentMovieDetail ? currentMovieDetail.poster_path : ""}`} />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="movie__detailRight">
                    <div className="movie__detailRightTop">
                        <div className="movie__name">{currentMovieDetail ? currentMovieDetail.original_title : ""}</div>
                        <div className="movie__tagline">{currentMovieDetail ? currentMovieDetail.tagline : ""}</div>
                        <div className="movie__rating">
                            {currentMovieDetail ? currentMovieDetail.vote_average: ""} <i class="fas fa-star" />
                            <span className="movie__voteCount">{currentMovieDetail ? "(" + currentMovieDetail.vote_count + ") votes" : ""}</span>
                        </div>  
                        <div className="movie__runtime">{currentMovieDetail ? currentMovieDetail.runtime + " mins" : ""}</div>
                        <div className="movie__releaseDate">{currentMovieDetail ? "Release date: " + currentMovieDetail.release_date : ""}</div>
                        <div className="movie__genres">
                            {
                                currentMovieDetail && currentMovieDetail.genres
                                ? 
                                currentMovieDetail.genres.map(genre => (
                                    <><span className="movie__genre" id={genre.id}>{genre.name}</span></>
                                )) 
                                : 
                                ""
                            }
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="movie__detailRightBottom">
                        <div className="synopsisText">Synopsis</div>
                        <div>{currentMovieDetail ? currentMovieDetail.overview : ""}</div>
                    </div>
                    
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="movie__links">
                <div className="movie__heading">Useful Links</div>
                {
                    currentMovieDetail && currentMovieDetail.homepage && <a href={currentMovieDetail.homepage} target="_blank" style={{textDecoration: "none"}}><p><span className="movie__homeButton movie__Button">Homepage <i className="newTab fas fa-external-link-alt"></i></span></p></a>
                }
                {
                    currentMovieDetail && currentMovieDetail.imdb_id && <a href={"https://www.imdb.com/title/" + currentMovieDetail.imdb_id} target="_blank" style={{textDecoration: "none"}}><p><span className="movie__imdbButton movie__Button">IMDb<i className="newTab fas fa-external-link-alt"></i></span></p></a>
                }
            </div>
            <div className="movie__heading">Production companies</div>
            <div className="movie__production">
                {
                    currentMovieDetail && currentMovieDetail.production_companies && currentMovieDetail.production_companies.map(company => (
                        <>
                            {
                                company.logo_path 
                                && 
                                <span className="productionCompanyImage">
                                    <img className="movie__productionComapany" src={"https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original" + company.logo_path} />
                                    <span>{company.name}</span>
                                </span>
                            }
                        </>
                    ))
                }
            </div>
        
        </div>
    )
}

export default Movie
```

**MovieDetails.css**

```
.movie {
    height: max-content;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
    flex-direction:column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: flex-start;
}

.movie__intro {
    width: 80%;
}

.movie__backdrop {
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    object-fit:cover;
    object-position: 0 35%;
}

.movie__detail {
    align-items: center;
    width: 75%;
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 225px;
}

.movie__detailLeft {
    margin-right: 30px;
}

.movie__poster {
    width:300px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.86) 0px 22px 40px 6px;
}

.movie__detailRight {
    color: white;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 450px;
    justify-content:space-between ;
}

.movie__detailRightTop > div{
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #000000;
    margin-bottom: .5rem;
}

.movie__name {
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 3rem;
}

.movie__voteCount {
    margin-left: 1rem;
}

.movie__genres {
    margin: 1.25rem 0;
}

.movie__genre {
    padding: .5rem;
    border: 2px solid white;
    border-radius: 20px;
    margin-right: 1rem;
}


.movie__detailRightBottom {
    margin: 2rem 0;
    flex: 0.8;
}

.synopsisText {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    margin-bottom: 1.25rem;
    font-weight: 600;
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    align-items: center;
}
.synopsisText > div:last-of-type {
    margin-left: auto;
}

.movie__links {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 120px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 75%;
}

.movie__heading {
    font-size: 2.2rem;
}

.movie__Button {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0.8rem 2rem;
    border-radius: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 150px;
    color: black;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.movie__homeButton {
    background-color:rgb(255, 0, 0);
    
}

.movie__imdbButton {
    background-color:#f3ce13;
}

.newTab {
    margin-left: 1.4rem;
}

.movie__production {
    width: 85%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: flex-end;
    margin-bottom: 4rem;
}


.movie__productionComapany {
    width: 200px;
    margin: 2rem;
}

.productionCompanyImage {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```